# Kafka Connect Transformations - RegexRouter replacement topic names in lowercase

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We are trying to setup a connector (Debezium) in Kafka Connect and transform all the topic names generated by this connector via regular expressions. The regex below is working and detects the patterns we want, but **we also need to create all the topic names in lowercase.**

We have tried to put this in the replacement expression as **\L$1** but it is just **printing and L in front of our topic names**, for example **LOutbound.Policy** instead of **outbound.policy**

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

This is the connector curl command

```
curl -i -X PUT http://kafka-alpha-cp-kafka-connect:8083/connectors/kafka-bi-datacontract/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"name": "kafka-bi-datacontract",
"connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
"database.hostname" : "ukdb3232123",
"database.server.name" : "ukdb3232123\\perf",
"database.port" : "12442",
"database.user" : "KafkaConnect-BI",
"database.password" : "*******",
"database.dbname" : "BeazleyIntelligenceDataContract",
"snapshot.lock.timeout.ms" : "10000000",
"table.whitelist" : "Outbound.Policy,Outbound.Section",
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka-alpha-cp-kafka-headless:9092",
"database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.bidatacontract",
"transforms": "dropTopicPrefix",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"^[^.]+.(.*)",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"\\L$1"
}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\L$1` or `\\L$1` would be the same as `L$1`.

You would need to create/find your own transform for lowercasing.

Once you do, you can do something like this

```
"transforms": "dropTopicPrefix,lowertopic",

"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"^[^.]+.(.*)",
"transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"$1",

"transforms.lowerTopic.type":"com.example.foo.LowerCase$Topic",
```

Comment: Thanks for this cricket_007 I will explore this route and post here if we manage to get this done.

Comment: @DavidGMediavilla have you managed to get this working? I am also currently looking to do the same, but in my case I need to convert lowercase to uppercase.

Comment: @Nomad See here how to write your own transform https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: if someone want's to remove all prefixes ([instance].[schema].[table] to only [table]) this regex should do the job: ^[^.]+.[^.]++.(.*)